# Can't import picamera

Tags: python, camera

I've installed picamera with `pip install picamera`, but I can't import it. I get this error message instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/picamera/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from picamera.exc import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 41, in <module>
    import picamera.mmal as mmal
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/picamera/mmal.py", line 153, in <module>
    class MMAL_FOURCC_T(ct.c_uint32):
TypeError: __class__ set to <class 'picamera.mmal.MMAL_FOURCC_T'> defining 'MMAL_FOURCC_T' as <class 'picamera.mmal.MMAL_FOURCC_T'>
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Found a corresponding issue in the [official Github repository](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/355). Seems like there is no solution yet.

Comment: Yup, this is an issue in Python 3.6 itself. For now, I'd suggest just using Python 3.4 (which is the standard Python 3 on Raspbian). Could I ask what distro you're using? (I'm intrigued what distro is on 3.6 already, which has only been released recently)

Comment: [Arch Linux ARM](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3) is on Python 3.6. Installed it with the instructions on the site I just linked and then installed Python via pacman.

Comment: Oh, someone's done a pacman package for picamera? That's good to know (there's an ancient ticket for that in the repo which I can tick off :-). Still, slightly surprised they're on python 3.6 mere days after it was released - certainly unusual for Linux (most distros are a lot more conservative about updates)

Comment: I don't know, I've installed picamera via pip (see the original question).

Comment: Oh sorry, read python as picamera, oops! Problem with skimming things on a mobile when I'm in the kitchen...

Comment: No problem :) Do you know if there is anything I could do to get this working? Would prefer not to hack my way back to an older version of Python.

Comment: I'll try and post a patch to the ticket linked above a bit later on when I'm back at the PC - shouldn't be a complex one as the issue only affects one minor class.

Comment: May as well make an official answer for this as well to save people jumping around for the patch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an upstream issue with Python 3.6.0 itself (see [issue 29270](http://bugs.python.org/issue29270)). My hope is that there'll be some fix upstream before 3.6.x makes it into Raspbian, but in the meantime (for people on other distros like Arch which has already jumped to 3.6) the following simple patch to the installation should get things working again:

```
diff --git a/picamera/mmal.py b/picamera/mmal.py
index cd77362..2bd92c7 100644
--- a/picamera/mmal.py
+++ b/picamera/mmal.py
@@ -152,10 +152,7 @@ MMAL_TIME_UNKNOWN = ct.c_int64(1<<63)

 class MMAL_FOURCC_T(ct.c_uint32):
     def __eq__(self, other):
-        if isinstance(other, int):
-            return self.value == other
-        else:
-            return super(MMAL_FOURCC_T, self).__eq__(other)
+        return self.value == other

     def __str__(self):
         return ''.join(chr(self.value >> i & 0xFF) for i in range(0, 32, 8))
```

As noted in the associated [picamera ticket (#355)](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/355) this isn't a particularly good fix, and I'll include something better in 1.13, but it's the simplest patch that'll get things working again in 1.12.